# Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'self'

Tags: iframe

I am embedding an iFrame in my web page, something like this:

```
var iframeProps = {
        'data-type': self.props.type,
        allowTransparency: self.props.allowTransparency,
        className: self.props.className,
        frameBorder: self.props.frameBorder,
        height: self.props.height,
        key: url,
        onLoad: self.props.onLoad.bind(self),
        scrolling: self.props.scrolling,
        src: self.state.isActive ? url : '',
        style: self.props.styles,
        width: self.props.width
    };
<iframe {...iframeProps} />
```

This is throwing an error in the console

> Refused to display 'https://twitter.com/.... in a frame because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'self'".

Could anyone please tell me how can I make this work?

Comment: If a site is disallowing frames with frame-ancestors or X-Frame-Options, you simply can't iframe it. Depending on the source and what you need from it, there may be an API or SDK available. So really, you can't make what you're doing work, but you can approach it a different way by tapping into their approved interface systems.

Answer (score 49):

The content is prohibited from being displayed within an IFRAME due the Content Security Policy being set.  The webserver hosting [twitter.com](http://twitter.com) is configured to add a HTTP header to the response object.  Specifically they are setting the Content-Security-Policy tag to frame-ancestors 'self'.  There is no way you'll be able to embed their pages into a page of your own using IFRAME.  There are other techniques that you could use to work around that, but none are as simple as an iframe tag.

[W3C Content Security Policy Level 3 - Frame Ancestors](https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-csp/#directive-frame-ancestors)

Comment: What are those other techniques please?

Comment: any updates on anything that can be done? for example, i want to show something from another site of mine, not twitter.com

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question and should be a comment instead. An appropriate answer would give an example of a solution.

Comment: @msysmilu — If you want to allow your site to be displayed in a frame then don't add a CSP that forbids it!

Comment: @JGallardo It does answer the question -- it's just not possible unless twitter.com decides to change their `Content-Security-Policy` to allow your domain.  These controls are in place to help the host (in this case, twitter.com) protect its assets from exploitation and/or abuse.

Comment: @heez, No. while his comment is valid, it is not an actual working answer because you can't take anything from here and directly implement it. Hence it is a comment, regardless of how accurate it is. An "answer" would either provide an example or  formula to arrive at a working solution. Here though the author simply states, "There are other techniques that you could use." But did not articulate on any of those.

Comment: The OP asked, "Could anyone please tell me how can I make this work?". They did not ask, "why does it not work". They were looking for something to get their project working. Anything less than that is a comment.

Comment: @JGallardo I think an answer that explains why the OP wont be able to do it is also considered an answer. For example if I say "I'm trying to do this but haven't figured out how" and if it is actually not possible to do it that way I should need to know that I am going down the wrong road and it is not possible.

Comment: You can disagree @Craig, but the question specifically stated "Could anyone please tell me how can I make this work?" Hence a response that says [paraphrased] "you can't make it work that way" is not at all accomplishing the objective.

Comment: @JGallardo Let's say you're trying to use synthetic wings to fly and you're not successful at it so you ask: "how can I make this work?". Someone answers "humans can't fly with synthetic wings due to a lack of muscle power, bad aerodynamics, and weight". That is a perfectly correct answer, not a comment. Because "this" in your question means "using synthetic wings", like "this" in the OP's question means "using an iframe". It just can't be done and that is the answer. The person answering you doesn't have to tell you how to buy a plane ticket. You didn't ask for alternative flying methods.

Comment: @jgozal for something to qualify as an answer it has to comply within the desired outcome, otherwise it is a comment. If I asked scientists of the 1940s "how do i fly to the moon?" and they answered "humans will never land on the moon", are they giving me the answer to how to get to the moon? no they are giving me their opinion(comment).

Answer (score 3):

I encountered with this problems recently too and i didn't find any alternative method to solve that.Finally, I came up with idea that the attribute in the iframe,which is "src",can be filled with the origin html content and it works.

```js
// this demo shows the process of getting the html content 
// from the link,and then apply it to the attribute "src" in the iframe
$.get(link, function (response){ 
var html = response;
var html_src = 'data:text/html;charset=utf-8,' + html;
$("#iframeId").attr("src" , html_src);
});
```

Comment: This gives the error: "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource".  The browser is blocking cross-origin requests.

Comment: This answer just happens to work because the target resource allow cross-origin access.

Comment: any solution to get around cross-origin access?

Answer (score 3):

You could use a proxy which fetches the requested page on your behalf and then you can host the proxy on your domain and load the web page from this proxy server with the new proxy URL rather then "twitter.com" in this question.

Comment: for one page this is possible, but when loading a page that contain many requests with ajax this will be a problem to rewrite all urls and traite them with the proxy conditions

Comment: Yes , that is the most tricky part. I do have a code for it, but not sure if its appropriate to share it here.