# Opening a link inside a div in the modal

Tags: jquery, html, hyperlink, bootstrap-4, html-object

I have a modal in which there are 2 `<a>` tags. When a user clicks the link, the link should be opened in the same div of the same modal and **not in the tab**.

For this I tried:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#help_modal a").each(function() {
    $("#help_modal").load($(this).attr("href"));
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
    Open modal
  </button>

  <!-- The Modal -->
  <div class="modal" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">

        <!-- Modal Header -->
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Heading</h4>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        </div>

        <!-- Modal body -->
        <div class="modal-body" id="help_modal">
          <a href="https://google.com" class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-primary">Open Google</a>
          <a href="https://stackoverflow.com" class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-secondary">Open Stackoverflow</a>
        </div>

        <!-- Modal footer -->
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

But the link is opening in the same tab...

### UPDATE

I also tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56513694/11621009), but it also didn't work for me after [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56513343/opening-a-link-inside-a-div-in-the-modal#comment99614103_56513694).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Answer to your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56513343/opening-a-link-inside-a-div-in-the-modal#comment99614103_56513694):

If you check the console while running the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/msd8heu3/) it says,

> Refused to display
>   '[Opening a link inside a div in the modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56513343/opening-a-link-inside-a-div-in-the-modal/)'
>   in a frame because an ancestor violates the following Content Security
>   Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'self'".

Which means,

The content is prohibited from being displayed within an <kbd>IFRAME</kbd> due to the Content Security Policy being set. The web server hosting stackoverflow.com is configured to add an HTTP header to the response object. Specifically, they are setting the Content-Security-Policy tag to frame-ancestors 'self'. There is no way you'll be able to embed their pages into a page of your own using IFRAME.

Thanks to [TimmyB's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38269964/7678788).

---

#### Answer to your [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56513343/7678788):

**[Learner's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56513694/7678788) is also a good option. (+1)**

But I will prefer to have different **iframe(s)** and display them through the button.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".modal_button_example_com_self").click(function() {
    $('.modal_button_self').hide();
    $('#example_com').attr("style", "");
  });

  $(".modal_button_example_net_self").click(function() {
    $('.modal_button_self').hide();
    $('#example_net').attr("style", "");
  });

  $(".close_self").click(function() {
    $('.modal_button_self').attr("style", "");
    $('#example_com').hide();
    $('#example_net').hide();
  });

});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
        Open modal
    </button>

  <!-- The Modal -->
  <div class="modal" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">

        <!-- Modal Header -->
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Heading</h4>
          <button type="button" class="close close_self" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        </div>

        <!-- Modal body -->
        <div class="modal-body" id="help_modal">
          <button class="modal_button_self modal_button_example_com_self btn btn-block btn-lg btn-primary">Open Example.com</button>
          <button class="modal_button_self modal_button_example_net_self btn btn-block btn-lg btn-secondary">Open Example.net</button>

          <iframe id="example_com" style="display: none;" src="https://example.com/" width="100%" height="50%" seamless></iframe>
          <iframe id="example_net" style="display: none;" src="https://example.net/" width="100%" height="50%" seamless></iframe>

        </div>

        <!-- Modal footer -->
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger close_self" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I manage to achieve what you want with some javascript and the html 'object' tag:

I replace the content of your modal body with the content of the toReplace variable, containing an html 'object' element, use to embed the external link.

```
let el = document.getElementById("test");
let elToReplace = document.getElementById("help_modal");
let toReplace = "<object type=\"text/html\" data=\"https://gnu.org/\" width=\"100%\" height=\"600px\" style=\"overflow:auto;border:5px ridge blue\"> </object>";

function replaceInner() {
    elToReplace.innerHTML = toReplace;
}

el.addEventListener("click", () => { replaceInner(); }, false);
```

See a working codepen here : https://codepen.io/marc-simplon/pen/WBVmYW

Comment: When I try `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56513343/opening-a-link-inside-a-div-in-the-modal` instead of `https://gnu.org/`, it doesn't work. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/msd8heu3/)

Comment: I don't know any other way to embed a website except with 'object'  or 'iframe'. Maybe you just can't (if the website doesn't allow it) ?