# How to use Iframe in angular 7

Tags: angular

I am using Iframe to set external URL in a HTML using below methods:

Method 1:

```
 <iframe [src]="sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(srcUrl)" height="600" width="1000"></iframe>
```

Method 2:  In this method I also created a Safe PIPE using [How to set <iframe src="..."> without causing `unsafe value` exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38037760/how-to-set-iframe-src-without-causing-unsafe-value-exception/38037914#38037914)

```
 <iframe width="100%" height="300" [src]="srcUrl | safe"></iframe>
```

Method 3:

```
 <iframe #iframe height="600" width="1000"></iframe> 
  @ViewChild('iframe') iframe: ElementRef;
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.iframe.nativeElement.setAttribute('src', this.srcUrl);
}
```

But none is working for me. I am getting below error:

Refused to display '' in a frame because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'self' ".

Please find my code at below link :

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-irwasj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html
Can anyone please help in it?

Comment: post the error you'r getting or create a stackblitz of your problem

Comment: Hi I have edited my question with error message.

Comment: can i get the example url that you are trying to access?as per this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38269964/5621827) there are setting on the other end and you can't access that url in iframe but we can try other way

Comment: I am using  srcUrl: string = "https://stackoverflow.com/". also upadated quation with Stackblitz link.

Comment: as specified in above post you can't do that other alternative to get and use as html will also fail because of `CORS` policy

Answer (score 5):

I was looking into this. Few website like google, stackoverflow, youtube denies to load inside an iframe. It uses some sort of FrameKiller. If you use `https://www.google.com` it will show google.com refuse to connect. Other sites like stackoverflow simply doesn't show any message. I have created a demo for the same that loads some other random site with `https`.

DEMO: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gzvckb

Comment: Please accept as answer if it answers your query. Happy Coding :)