# ReactJS - Customer messenger CHAT violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors

Tags: reactjs, facebook, frame, content-security-policy, messenger

I test on my local environment the plugins react-messenger-customer-chat.
I just installed the plugin and insert this folowing code in my render view

```js
    render() {
        const { src, title, tracks, scrollTop } = this.state;
        return (
            <div id="lz-app">
                <Header scrollTop={scrollTop}/>
                <main className="main">
                    <MessengerCustomerChat
                            pageId="xxxxxx"
                            appId="xxxxxx"
                     />
                </main>
                <Footer/>
          
                   
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
```

When run my react app , i have the error :

Refused to frame 'https://web.facebook.com/' because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors https://web.facebook.com".
[image]

How I resolve this issue please?
Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'self'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37799258/content-security-policy-directive-frame-ancestors-self)

Comment: @Emile , Perhaps, but i don't understand, what is the bettter solution

Comment: There's probably none as it's Facebook that's limiting which domains can embed their messenger app inside of an iframe.

Comment: The [whitelisted domains](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/facebook-chat-plugin/#whitelist-the-domain-of-your-website) can possibly be managed inside the client's facebook developer account, though I'm not personally familiar with it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution here
Solution here
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8e_4KIj4jBs

Answer (score 0):

You need to whitelist your domain in the Facebook page settings. To do this, navigate to: `Your FB Page > Settings > Advanced Messaging > White-listed domains` and enter your domain here.